# Exporting XY-data to a new shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, export, csv

I've got a CSV file with 29 rows and 2146 columns including coordinates and a number of reflectance for each wavelength starting from 350 up to 2500.
I imported the CSV file in QGIS without any problems. But when I want to write my data as a new shapefile, I got the following error:

> (OGR-Fehler: Can't create field W2392 in Shape DBF file, reason unknown.)

Is there field number limitation of attribute table for exporting it as new shapefile using QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols.  By asking how to do the same thing in either of two products you are effectively asking two questions which makes this too broad.  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to focus your question on one or other.  I recommend asking about the one you are most likely to use.  You can always ask about the other one in a separate question.

Comment: You can't get **any** GIS product to do this, because it is impossible. Technically, the dBase-III+ specification states that dBase files are limited to 100 columns, but most implementations permit the physical maximum of 255 (one byte is allocated). In order to exceed 255 colums you need a different format.

Comment: You could try postgis, geopackage or spatiallite.  But think about what you are trying to achieve - you want to save an array of values, maybe an array field would work better?

Comment: Not possible, check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile in particular the data storage limitations section...